# How to arrange Bootstrap alerts into two columns?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, alert

I have a very simple to-do like page where I can enter members and remove them or mark them as done. The members are Bootstrap alerts, so far so good.

My problem is, that the alert/members are too wide and should be in two or three columns, to be able to view more of them on the screen.

This is where I get stuck, because the grid system doesn't want it. I don't know what am I missing...

Can someone please help me, how to rearrange the member list into two or three columns?

I tried with the columns with the `team1` button.

This is the JSFiddle URL for it: https://jsfiddle.net/voriand/zsfo65wb/

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.btn-addmember').click(function() {
    if ($('#text').val().length != 0) {
      var x = $('#memberlist').html();
      var y =
        `<div class="alert alert-success alert-dismissible fade in">
        <a href="#" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-label="close">×</a>
                            ` + $('#text').val() + `</div>`;
      $('#memberlist').html(y + x);
      $('#text').val("");
    } else alert("Please, enter the name of the member");
  });
  
  //Adding members of team1
  $('.btn-team1').click(function() {
    if ($('#team1').val().length != 0) {
      var members = $('#team1').val().split('\n');

      for (var i = 0; i < members.length; i++) {
        var x = $('#memberlist').html();
        var y =
          `<div class="col-sm"><div class="alert alert-success alert-dismissible fade in">
                                        <a href="#" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-label="close">×</a>
                                        <b>` + members[i] + `</b></div></div>`;
        if (members[i].trim().length > 0) {
          $('#memberlist').html(y + x);
        }
      }
    }
  });

  //Adding members of team2
  $('.btn-team2').click(function() {
    if ($('#team2').val().length != 0) {
      var members = $('#team2').val().split('\n');

      for (var i = 0; i < members.length; i++) {
        var x = $('.container').html();
        var y =
          `<div class="alert alert-success alert-dismissible fade in">
                                        <a href="#" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-label="close">×</a>
                                        <b>` + members[i] + `</b></div>`;
        if (members[i].trim().length > 0) {
          $('.container').html(y + x);
        }
      }
    }
  });
  // When Member is clicked
  $(document).on('click', '.alert', function() {
    if ($(this).css('text-decoration-line') == "none") {
      $(this).css('text-decoration-line', 'line-through');
      $(this).css('background-color', '#dddddd');
      $(this).css('border-color', '#dddddd');
    } else {
      $(this).css('text-decoration-line', 'none');
      $(this).css('background-color', '#dff0d8');
      $(this).css('border-color', '#d6e9c6');
    }
  });
});
```

```css
.container {
  width: 80%;
  height: auto;
}

.foot {
  position: fixed;
  left: 10%;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 80%;
  text-align: center;
}

.form-group {
  height: 0px;
  visibility: hidden;
}

.copyright {
  width: 100%;
  text-align: right;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<center>

  <div class="foot">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-sm-1"> </div>
      <div class="col-sm-10">
        <!-- Input for members -->
        <div class="input-group">
          <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Add member" id="text">
          <div class="input-group-btn">
            <button class="btn btn-success btn-addmember">
                <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus">
                </i></button>
          </div>
          <div class="input-group-btn">
            <button class="btn btn-success btn-team1">
                <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus">
                </i> TEAM1</button>
          </div>
          <div class="input-group-btn">
            <button class="btn btn-success btn-team2">
                <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus">
                </i> TEAM2</button>
          </div>
        </div>
        <br>
        <br>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
      <label for="exampleFormControlTextarea1">Team1</label>
      <textarea class="form-control" id="team1" rows="3">
        vivamus eget 
        lacus vitae 
        mi vulputate 
        varius integer 
        suscipit orci 
        condimentum
        vestibulum
        </textarea>
      <label for="exampleFormControlTextarea1">Team2</label>
      <textarea class="form-control" id="team2" rows="3">
        vivamus eget 
        lacus vitae 
        mi vulputate 
        varius integer 
        suscipit orci 
        condimentum
        vestibulum
        </textarea>
    </div>
    <p class="copyright">Created by: Me - <a href="mailto:me@me.com">me@me.com</a></p>
  </div>

  <br>
  <h2 class="text text-success">Team Members</h2>
  <br>

  <div class="container-fluid">
    <div id="memberlist" class="row">

    </div>
  </div>
</center>
```

Comment: In the JS, where you set the value for `y` when clicking `+`, add the class `col-sm-4` before the `alert` classes. Then try, is this what you're looking for?

Comment: Protips: `<center>` is [deprecated](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/center), and `<br>` shouldn't be used for layout purposes. Bootstrap provides gobs of spacing classes for that. (Correction, ancient v3 doesn't. Why not update?? Still... use CSS.) Also, it's not advisable to style core Bootstrap classes like `.container` and `.form-group`, especially across the board. Use a custom class, if anything.

Comment: @SiddharthBhansali, please be sure to provide a proper answer below so the question can be resolved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. clarify HTML:

   - use CSS `margin` property instead of `<br>`
   - use the `text-center` class instead of `center` tag
   - place footer at the end of HTML in the `<footer>` tag
   - use `.container` instead of `.container-fluid` and empty columns
   - use hierarchy `.form-inline > .input-group > .input-group-btn` to organize inputs and buttons as inline form
2. CSS:

   - I've removed some CSS instructions and restored original behavior of
     Bootstrap's container. I recommend to use Bootstrap 4 or 5 with
     flex-boxes to achieve more flexible possibilities.
   - I've added styles for `form-inline` block to improve its layout on he narrow screen.
3. Redo JS:

   - wrap the alert HTML code in a separate function `addMember`
   - add one more function for adding of teams by the textarea's id
   - simplify `click` code for the buttons with a help of these two functions
   - use [`.toggleClass()`](https://api.jquery.com/toggleclass/) instead of `.css()` to change the alerts appearance on click
   - use [`.append()`](https://api.jquery.com/append/) to add new alert at the end of the list
4. Make columns:

   - Wrap alerts in the column block to place several alerts in a line.
   - Add two classes `col-xs-6 col-sm-4` to organize alerts in 2 columns on mobile and in 3 columns on the wide screen.
   - Now Bootstrap's [dismissible
     alerts](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/3.4/components/#alerts-dismissible) are not enough, because we have to remove the column block too. So we can remove the `alert-dismissible` class and the `data-dismiss`attribute. I've added alternative member closing code by jQuery too.

https://codepen.io/glebkema/pen/jOLJYJE

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var memberList = $("#memberlist");

  memberList.on("click", ".alert", function() {
    $(this).toggleClass("member-clicked");
  });

  memberList.on("click", ".close", function() {
    var memberColumn = $(this).parent().parent();
    memberColumn.fadeOut();
  });

  $(".btn-addmember").click(function() {
    var newMember = $("#text").val().trim();
    if (newMember) {
      addMember(newMember);
    } else {
      alert("Please, enter the name of the member");
    }
    $("#text").val("");
  });

  $(".btn[data-team]").click(function() {
    addTeam($(this).data("team"));
  });

  function addMember(member) {
    member = member.trim();
    if (member) {
      memberList.append(
        `<div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-4"><div class="alert alert-success">` +
        `<span class="close" aria-label="close">&times;</span>` +
        member +
        `</div></div>`
      );
    }
  }

  function addTeam(id) {
    var team = $("#" + id).val().trim();
    if (team) {
      var members = team.split("\n");
      console.log(members);
      for (var i = 0; i < members.length; i++) {
        addMember(members[i]);
      }
    }
  }
});
```

```css
.footer {
  position: fixed;
  left: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  right: 0;
}

/* create a class for .toggleClass() */
.alert.member-clicked {
  text-decoration-line: line-through;
  background-color: #ddd;
  border-color: #ddd;
}

/* use margin instead of <br> */
.copyright {
  margin-top: 10px;
}

/* use these values not only when the screen is wider than 768 pixels */
.form-inline.form-members .input-group {
  display: inline-table;
  vertical-align: middle;
}
.form-inline.form-members .input-group .input-group-btn {
  width: auto;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@3.4.1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="container">
  <h2 class="text text-success text-center">Team Members</h2>
  <div id="memberlist" class="row"></div>
</div>

<footer class="footer">
  <div class="container">
    <!-- Input for members -->
    <div class="form-inline form-members">
      <div class="input-group">
        <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Add member" id="text">
        <div class="input-group-btn">
          <button class="btn btn-success btn-addmember"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus"></i></button>
        </div>
      </div>
      <button class="btn btn-success" data-team="team1"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus"></i> TEAM1</button>
      <button class="btn btn-success" data-team="team2"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus"></i> TEAM2</button>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group hidden">
      <label for="exampleFormControlTextarea1">Team1</label>
      <textarea class="form-control" id="team1" rows="7">
        1 vivamus eget 
        1 lacus vitae 
        1 mi vulputate 
        1 varius integer 
        1 suscipit orci 
        1 condimentum
        1 vestibulum
      </textarea>

      <label for="exampleFormControlTextarea1">Team2</label>
      <textarea class="form-control" id="team2" rows="7">
        2 vivamus eget 
        2 lacus vitae 
        2 mi vulputate 
        2 varius integer 
        2 suscipit orci 
        2 condimentum
        2 vestibulum
      </textarea>
    </div>

    <p class="copyright text-right">Created by: Me - <a href="mailto:me@me.com">me@me.com</a></p>
  </div>
</footer>
```

Comment: Wow, just wow. This answer is very detailed, very improving. Thank you for taking the time and effort to write this together!!

Answer (score 0):

However much your layout can be improved, other answers here have already did that for you. But if you're looking to just break the alert into 3 columns without having to change your entire code, just add the class `col-sm-4` (which will produce 3 columns on the viewport from the small screen size) on your JS line where you assign the value to `y`. So that particular statement now becomes:

`var y = "<div class='alert alert-success alert-dismissible fade in'><a href='#' class='close' data-dismiss='alert' aria-label='close'>×</a>" + $('#text').val() + "</div>";`